# Eloquent: Two foreign keys in a table pointing to the same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models:

- Team
- Game (Played between two games)

The Game model has two foreign keys pointing to the Team model - team1_id & team2_id.

Here's the code for Team model:

```
class Team extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'team';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'color',
        'year'
    ];

    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Game::class);
    }
}
```

Code for Game model:

```
class Game extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'game';

    protected $casts = [
        'team1_id' => 'int',
        'team2_id' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'team1_id',
        'team2_id',
        'location',
        'start_at'
    ];

    public function team1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Team::class, 'team1_id');
    }

    public function team2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Team::class, 'team2_id');
    }
}
```

I get an error saying the column could not be found.

```
return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Game::class, 'team1_id');
```

This works, but the problem is that I want to get games depending on both team1_id and team2_id.

Answer (score 0):

You had to specify the foreign key and the local key you use to reference that relation

```
public function localTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Team::class, 'id', 'team1_id');
}

public function foreignTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Team::class, 'id', 'team2_id');
}
```